# JOOQ log with MDC

Tags: jooq

I use logback MDC to record my application defferent module's log, for example,

```
// 1. define a logger
org.slf4j.Logger mdclog = org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger("MY_LOGGER_NAME");

// record trade log
org.slf4j.MDC.put("MY_MDC_KEY", "trade_log");
mdclog.info("This is trade log");

// record goods log
org.slf4j.MDC.put("MY_MDC_KEY", "goods_log");
mdclog.info("This is goods log");
```

mdc config in logback.xml

```
<appender name="log_classify" class="ch.qos.logback.classic.sift.SiftingAppender">
        <discriminator>
            <Key>login</Key> 
            <DefaultValue>OTHER</DefaultValue>
        </discriminator>
        <sift>
            <appender name="${MY_MDC_KEY}" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
                <prudent>false</prudent>
                <file>${LOG_PATH}/${MY_MDC_KEY}.log</file>
                <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
                    <fileNamePattern>${LOG_PATH}/${MY_MDC_KEY}_%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log.zip</fileNamePattern>
                </rollingPolicy>
                <encoder>
                    <pattern>${FILE_LOG_PATTERN}</pattern>
                </encoder>
            </appender>
        </sift>
</appender>
```

this generate two log file,
[image: result]

I want to record trade or goods sql log in defferent log file,
so I wonder if JOOQ does support this ?

Answer (score 1):

I find a way to resove my question.

I put my appender into `org.jooq.tools.LoggerListener`,

```
    <Logger name="org.jooq.tools.LoggerListener" level="DEBUG">
        <appender-ref ref="log_classify" />
    </Logger>
```

the jooq sql excute log will be add to defferent file after initialise my MDC.

Actually, I don’t know if this is a good idea

Answer (score 0):

jOOQ doesn't integrate this deeply with loggers out of the box, but you can place your `org.slf4j.MDC.put` calls in an [`ExecuteListener`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org.jooq/org/jooq/ExecuteListener.html) prior to running a SQL query, for example in the [`ExecuteListener::renderEnd`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org.jooq/org/jooq/ExecuteListener.html#renderEnd(org.jooq.ExecuteContext)) event, once the SQL statement is generated, and regex-match the query to make a decision. Alternatively, using a [`VisitListener`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org.jooq/org/jooq/VisitListener.html), you can make this decision already earlier, trying to match specific tables that may be present in queries.

But quite probably, a much better place to initialise your `MDC` context would be on the service layer, because your service will probably also know if you're about to run "trade" or "goods" queries.

Comment: Hi, Lukas, thanks for your answer. I find a way to resove my question.    

I add it at the end of the question.  

but I don’t know if this is a good idea,

Comment: @einherjar: You can answer your own questions